# Choosing which duplicate answer to delete

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, moderation

2-3 years ago I came across this question: [Understanding colors on Android (six characters)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445085)

I found the answer by BlondeFurious helpful and I decided to post an [improved answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25170174/1048340). It became a popular answer and I was happy to contribute. Months later I found that the question is a duplicate (see [Hex transparency in colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15852122/hex-transparency-in-colors?lq=1)). The duplicate answer gets a lot more traffic. I decided to post my answer there too. My answer was well received.

At the time I didn't know duplicate answers were deleted by mods. Today I needed to reference my own answer. I googled "hex transparency colors" and the duplicate is the top result on Google. I noticed my question was deleted by @Flexo (I'm guessing because it is a duplicate answer).

I understand the reasoning behind deleting duplicate answers, however, it would be nice to have a say in which answer was deleted. Deleting an answer that many users found helpful seems to devalue stackoverflow, even if it is a duplicate.

Comment: Well, by raising it on meta, there is a decent chance to get this some mod attention as to which one of the answers gets to stay. Otherwise, you can raise a modflag.

Comment: It just doesn't make any sense to have the exact same answer on a duplicate question.  So the mod kept the one on the dup target.  Very hard to imagine that anybody, or you, would prefer it the other way around since just about nobody would see it.  This is otherwise entirely under your control, just don't post duplicate answers on identical questions and nobody can make the "wrong" choice.

Comment: Of course it isn't deleted, it still exists on the other question. Its more a problem of the deleted answer being found through google, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, the duplicate receives more views. As of now, ~265k more views. Of course, I would like my answer visible on both questions. In my view, more visibility for good answers is a win for everyone. I think this is a part of a larger problem, where questions with many more views than the original are marked as duplicates.